How do u download a blob url in python flask?
So i am basically POSTing an URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage) to my python/flask server which saves an blob:https.... url
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/process", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({img: URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage)}),
        //body: JSON.stringify({ img: selectedImage }), //ausprobieren 
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
          }
          return res.json();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Fetch error:", error);
        });

Now it goes to this python function and I don't get how to now get the image from this url
IF there is no way of retrieving it could you please link sources on how to POST Images on to your server with python flask in nextjs. (I am dying ⊂(◉‿◉)つ)
@app.route('/api/process', methods=["POST", "GET"]) 
def process():
 
    data = request.get_json()

    i = data.get('img',  "Key 'str' does not exist in the dictionary.")

    request.urlretrieve(file_url, "local-filename.jpg") #<====== here is da problemo
   

    resp = jsonify(data)
    return resp

I tried this request.urlretrieve(file_url, "local-filename.jpg") #<====== here is da problemo

you will need to know the pathname of where the file was saved to...
